# ThreadContext.pop() throwing NoSuchElementException: The ThreadContext stack is empty in log4j-2.3

Tags: java, log4j2

I am trying to upgrade from log4j-1.x to log4j-2.3 and getting bellow error on run time. Anything I am missing?

```
public void debug(String msg) {
    appendContext();
    logger.debug(msg);
    ThreadContext.pop();
}
```

> [5/25/16 20:08:16:748 SGT] 0000006a ServletWrappe E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E: An exception was thrown by one of the service methods of the servlet [MWServlet] in application [DBIN Middleware]. Exception created : [java.util.NoSuchElementException: The ThreadContext stack is empty
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.DefaultThreadContextStack.pop(DefaultThreadContextStack.java:185)
>       at org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext.pop(ThreadContext.java:391)

Comment: Did you add something to the ThreadContextStack on the same thread?

Comment: I have tried adding something but still got same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, we need to check ThreadContext is not empty before calling pop() on it:

```
public void debug(String msg) {
    appendContext();
    logger.debug(msg);
    if(!ThreadContext.isEmpty()){
        ThreadContext.pop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ThreadContext` object has both stack and map objects. `ThreadContext.isEmpty()` is a check on map while `ThreadContext.pop()` is on stack.

The below check worked for me :

```
   if (!ThreadContext.getImmutableStack().isEmpty()) {
        ThreadContext.pop();
    }
```